# Internet Connection Issue Ubuntu

Tags: server, internet, dns, ethernet

I have ethernet set up but I just can't seem to connect to the internet at all. I am aware this question has been repeatedly asked but I am a bit new to Ubuntu so please excuse if this is a trivial issue. I think part of what is making this complicated is the server is potentially on a firewall but I do not know 1.) how to confirm if it is and 2.) what I literally need to do to work around this. I tried configuring the network interface using `ifconfig` but I didn't get anything to change. Here is my Ubuntu version.

```
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Here is the `ifconfig` output.

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:97:56:f6:ae  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp38s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.115.60.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.115.60.255
        ether 2c:f0:5d:a1:a6:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 634047  bytes 244489362 (244.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 134689  bytes 11270400 (11.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10478  bytes 977682 (977.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10478  bytes 977682 (977.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The output from `ip r`

```
default via 10.115.60.1 dev enp38s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
10.115.60.0/24 dev enp38s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.115.60.150 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

And an attempt to ping Google

```
$ ping -c3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.251.35.164) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2037ms
```

```
$  cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search mc.cumc.columbia.edu
```

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$ ping 8.8.8.8` ? - if that works, check how to restore a working `nameserver`.

Comment: It is not responding :/, any clue what else I should check for?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.